# TypeError: 'Status' object is not iterable Twitter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

#Obtener informacion de otros usarios

```
data = api.get_user("NoticiasCaracol")
print( json.dumps(data._json, indent=4) )
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as pf:
    for obj in data:
        pf.write(json.dumps(obj) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're getting this error with this code, as there's no `Status` object involved. You should instead be getting `TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable` because it's not and `data` is a `User` object you're trying to iterate over.